# Python unable to append reading from files

Tags: python

So essentially I have the following text file

> hello you how are you doing?
>   i am doing well
>   is that so?
>   yes

I wish to append all the words into a new list where all words are larger than 3 and smaller than 7. My code is displayed below.

```
f=open("W7Ex11.txt","r")
words=[]
for line in f:
  line=line.rstrip()
  if len(line)>=3 and len(line)<=7:
    words.append(line)
f.close()
print(words)
```

Unfortunaly, I am getting only the last word appended, which is "yes". I honestly don't see why its going wrong. Any chance someone knows why my code isn't working as I want it to be?

result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWKNn.jpg

Comment: do you want `so?` to be included to to be removed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the line into words.  The split(char) function splits a string wherever it finds char.  Try this:

```
words = []

with open("W7Ex11.txt","r") as f: # will automatically close file afterwards
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()

        for word in line.split(' '):
            word = word.strip() # strip to remove whitespace around the word

            if 3 <= len(word) <= 7: # yes, you can do that in Python :)
                words.append(word)

print(words)
```

Comment: He wants the words, not the full lines.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file and search for the length of words and extract them

```
import re
with open("W7Ex11.txt","r") as f:
    a=' '.join(f.read().splitlines())
    re.findall('([\w\?]{3,7})',a)
```

Or

```
new_list=[]
for line in a:
    for i in re.finditer('([\w\?]{3,7})',line):
        new_list.append(line[i.start():i.end()+1].strip(' '))
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'you', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing?', 'doing', 'well', 'that', 'so?', 'yes']
```